# Android Firebase: user send data for manual inspection, make data available for everyone if inspection pass

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a multiuser app.
My users fill forms in my app that is sent to "uncheckedForms" in my firebase database. I need to **manually** check the forms they send.

A form is a Java object that has a boolean "isPassedInspection" instance variable that is set to *false* by default.

After my manual inspection, I set this instance variable to *true* directly from the firebase console, if by my standards this form has "passed"

On the other hand, I have a second Item in my database called "forms" that represents active forms that have already passed my manual inspection and their "isPassedInspection" is set to *true*.

All my app users read the same data. this data is retrieved from the "forms" and bound to a RecyclerView in my app.

This is an image of illustration

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to make the forms that I just checked and changed isPassedInspection to true, to automatically move from the "uncheckedForms" to "forms".

I would love to hear suggestions.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways in which you can achieve this. First solution would be client side, in which you can attach a `ValueEventListener` on the `isPassedInspection` property to check the value if it is true or false. If the value is `true`, then copy that object from `uncheckedForms` to `forms`. Obviously, don't forget to delete the form form `uncheckedForms`, once the form is successfully copied. The second approach would be to write a function in [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), that has the same purpose, to attach a listener on the same location and check if the value of `isPassedInspection` has changed, if it is changed to true then to copy the form in the other part. Satish Rajbhar's function might work, i didn't try it, but keep in mind that the benefit of this solution is that a form can be copied in the other side even if the user has the application closed.

If I were you, I would not have used this kind of database structure. I only have used a single node named `forms` and then query the database based on the `isPassedInspection` property. So, the main ideea is to display the user only the forms that are checked by you. The query should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("forms").orderByChild("isPassedInspection").equalsTo(true);
```

Comment: for simplicity, I decided to go with your 3rd solution and I have changed my database structure. I will use your second way and Satish #1 solution on my next update.

currently I am using a RecyclerView that takes CardViews. I was unable to query my database using the .child("forms").orderByChild("isPassedInspection").equalsTo(true);
Am I suppose to write this code inside the "onCreateViewHolder" ? 
can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: No. If you are using a `RecyclerView` together with a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` then you need to pass the above query to the `setQuery()` method of the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` and then pass the `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` object to your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. Please some code, to see more clearly.

Comment: Thank you alex, I edited the main question, you can see the code there. if you need any more code please let me know

Comment: The problem in your code is: `isInspectedFormQuery.toString()`. This line of code does not return a boolean or a String so you can compare it. If you try to print the value of this line, you'll that it will print an address, which is the address from the memory of the Query object. You don't need that if statement at all. Remove it from every place you are using it. It's completely wrong. There is no need to use an if statement at all because the query it self filters the results. Make the changes and keep me posted.

Comment: hey @Alex Mamo
since this applies only to my personal case and goes beyond my question above, I created a new question. if you would like to help [you can check it out here please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633754/create-a-cardview-only-if-object-have-a-specific-value-in-firebase)

Comment: I'll take a look. Do you think that my answer helped you in solving the initial issue?

Answer (score 1):

As you said you want to check forms from console and then transfer data from uncheckedForms to Forms. Here is the possible way you could implement.

Way 1. Use firebase cloud database functions.

- start observer in uncheckedForms
- When there is any change check is isPassedInspection==true.
- if true then copy data from uncheckedForms to forms
- remove data from uncheckedForms

  exports.checkedForms = functions.database.ref('/uncheckedForms/{formsKey}').onWrite(event=>{
              var itemKey=event.data.ref.parent.key;
              var formsData=event.data.val();
              if (formsData.isPassedInspection ==true) {
              formsData.isPassedInspection=true;
              var formsRoot=admin.database().ref("/forms").child(itemKey);
              formsRoot.set(formsData);
              var uncheckedFormsRoot=admin.database().ref("/uncheckedForms").child(itemKey);
              uncheckedFormsRoot.remove();
              }
  });
  // [image]

Way 2. You could handle this situation just by only Forms table without use of uncheckedForms. In ReyclerView only pass those items which have

```
isPassedInspection=true;
```

Comment: thank you satish. can you please provide a sample for way 2? I have a recyclerview that has CardViews in it. do i suppose to implement the isPassedInspection in the "onCreateViewHolder" ?

Comment: Can you show me codes where you have declared RecyclerView and Adapter.

Comment: yes satish, thank you. I edited the code in the main question. if you need more code please let me know and I will update it