# Create a CardView only if object have a specific value in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have objects in my firebase database called *userForm* .
Each *userForm* have an instance variable called *isPassedInspection* that is either set to true or false in my firebase.

users can send Form object to my firebase, therefore I manually set *isPassedInspection* to true once I consider the form they send as "approved" by my standards.

I would like that my RecyclerView only create CardViews for userForm that it's *isPassedInspection* is true, otherwise, don't create a CardView (return null).

This is my code:

```
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<userForm, userFormViewHolder>(options) {
    boolean isFormInspected;
    @Override
    public userFormViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        isPassedFormQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Log.e(TAG,"datasnapshot doesn't exist in db");
                }
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(singleSnapshot.exists()){
        //get the boolean variable from firebase for this item, and set it to "isFormInspected" 
         isFormInspected = singleSnapshot.getValue(userForm.class).isPassedInspection();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
            // if form is manually inspected create a CardView for that form, else return null
            if(isFormInspected){
            CardView cv =(CardView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.form_card, parent, false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Created a CardView");
            return new userFormViewHolder(cv);
            }
           else{
Log.e(TAG,"Form  is not inspected,so dont create a CardView");
           return null;
           }
    }
```

even though I know for sure that my item *isPassedInspection* is true, I always get this log I made:

> Form  is not inspected,so dont create a CardView

and after that this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.mItemViewType' on a
>   null object reference

any suggestions? thank you!

Comment: You're trying to access **isFormInspected** outiside the callback, so it will always be the same. You need to move the code inside the callback, because that way you guaranteed to have a value returned for isFormInspected

Comment: If I move my code inside the callback, meaning inside the **void onDateChange** method, I get an error "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type" because I am trying to return new userFormViewHolder(cv) inside a void method

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you should not be doing this firebase call inside your adapter. What I recommend you should do is you do a call in your activity and then you pass a list of userForm to your adapter. Then you can access isFormInspected directly from the parsed object instead of making the call and waiting for the value.

Comment: so if I make this firebase call:
1. Am I making a firebase call everytime a CardView is made?(therefore making too many firebase requests)
2.Following your suggestion, if I get it right, I should make a one time firebase call and get a boolean list: true or false, for all my userForm objects.
then I should pass that list to the adapter?

Comment: 1. Yep, also you won't be able to access your objects because you need first to wait the callback so the best approach is to get them all at once. 2 Yes, you could also get a list of userForms (you might need other information from the objects) and pass it to the adapter so you can access the isFormInspected inside the adapter. More importantly you'll be separating network calls from view rendering which is very important.

Comment: thank you!
last question please: If I make a call to firebase just once and receive this boolean list, what will happen if my database change? (for example, I add a new object) - will it interrupt the order between the boolean list and the firebase objects

Comment: Suppose you add the callback code to your activity and if you add the code that adds the list to your adapter inside the callback you list can be updated when the database updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your own adapter class.
you can see the codes.
UserForm.class

```
public class UserForm {
String name,birthday,hobby;
boolean isPassedInspection;

public UserForm(String name, String birthday, String hobby, boolean isPassedInspection) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.hobby = hobby;
    this.isPassedInspection = isPassedInspection;
}

public UserForm() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}

public String getHobby() {
    return hobby;
}

public void setHobby(String hobby) {
    this.hobby = hobby;
}

public boolean isPassedInspection() {
    return isPassedInspection;
}

public void setPassedInspection(boolean passedInspection) {
    isPassedInspection = passedInspection;
}}
```

// adapter class

```
public class FormsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormsViewHolder> {
private ArrayMap<String,UserForm> formsList=new ArrayMap<>();
/*use arrayMap to get from data and key */
public FormsAdapter() {
formsList=new ArrayMap<>();
}

@Override
public FormsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    // inflating card view item
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_card, parent, false);
    return new FormsViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FormsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String itemKey=formsList.keyAt(position);
    UserForm userForm=formsList.get(itemKey);
    // set one forms data
    holder.setFormsData(userForm);
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // handle click event
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return formsList.size();
}

public void addAFormItem(String key,UserForm userForm)
{
    if (!formsList.containsKey(key))
    {
        formsList.put(key,userForm);
        notifyItemInserted(formsList.size());
    }
} }
```

ViewHolder class

```
public class FormsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public View view;
public FormsViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    view=itemView;
}
public void setFormsData(UserForm userForm)
{
    // initialise card views items and set value in them
    TextView userName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    userName.setText(userForm.getName());
}}
```

your fragment

```
public class FormsListFragment extends Fragment {

private DatabaseReference formsRef;
private FormsAdapter adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forms_list, container, false);
    /**/
    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    adapter=new FormsAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    formsRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("forms");
    formsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            /*add data in adapter one by one if isPassedInspection true*/
            String itemKey=dataSnapshot.getKey();
            UserForm userForm=dataSnapshot.getValue(UserForm.class);
            if (userForm.isPassedInspection())
                adapter.addAFormItem(itemKey,userForm);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              /*when something change in data then add in adapter if isPassedInspection true*/
            String itemKey=dataSnapshot.getKey();
            UserForm userForm=dataSnapshot.getValue(UserForm.class);
            if (userForm.isPassedInspection())
                adapter.addAFormItem(itemKey,userForm);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return view;
}}
```

Comment: you really got out of your way to help me.. it works like charm!! thank you!!!
@Satish Rajbhar

Comment: Hey @Satish Rajbhar, can I make the order of the forms as I inserted using ArrayMap? from what I understand it manages memory better so I want to use it; however I realize that I should use LinkedHashMap to maintain order. what do you think?

Comment: Could you share screenshots of exact order of forms in database and the order you are getting in recyclerView. If issue gets resolved by using LinkedHashMap then go ahead.